# Can fields generated by an antenna damage an iPhone?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, interference

I am currently attending a radio technology course. We continuously work on radio sets that are sometimes used as manpacks by the Army. In order to learn how to operate them we work in close proximity to the sets and their antennas.

The antennas are generally whip type or long rods. Such as these :

[image]
[image]

The radio sets generally output around 25-50W in the 30-90MHz frequency range. Can that possibly cause damage to my iPhone?

Comment: There's probably some way that your iPhone can be damaged so there will be **no** sane engineer here telling you that you cannot damage the phone. In general the "is this safe" questions are unanswerable because I could prove to you that it is **unsafe** by doing whatever to damage your phone. Then your phone stops working and that proves it. Now how would I prove the opposite? I'd need to try out all possible scenarios. But then the one I forgot damages your phone. Lesson learned: it is **impossible** to prove that no damage will be done under all circumstances.

Comment: I would say it is *unlikely* that the phone will be damaged by this equipment.

Comment: I agree when there are only sane people around but then an idiot comes along and uses one of the antenna rods to trash your phone....

Comment: Sane engineer here, though wife might argue differently. It is not impossible. But, why do you ask?  Did your phone stop working? If so.. I change my answer to probably with whatever transmitters are attached to those antennas.

Comment: @Trevor If this can damage the phone I would rather start to worry about the health of people around.

Comment: @EugeneSh. true. but then again, for military work.. death from exposure to the antenna on the radio is the least of their worries.

Comment: @Trevor Millitary equipment is (supposed to be) strictly tested for safety and co-existence. Much more strictly than civil analogs (well, assuming the US and close allies origins).

Comment: @EugeneSh. coexistence with what? Other military equipment that is already hardened. A cheapo cell phone may not be so lucky. The DoD uses some nasty powerful stuff. BUt despite that I'd still think it unlikely it would kill an I-phone., but without knowing the transmitters attached... I can't rule it out either.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am only asking if in a normal day to day scenario would it damage my phone. I am not asking for proof either way. Just wanted to consult more learned men than myself to comment on it.

Comment: @Trevor My phone hasnt stopped working. I just thought about the effect of those electromagnetic wave's effect on the phone. If its any help, then the people teaching the course have always had phone with them and they havent had one fail on them just yet.

Comment: @TheBrokenBee Then you can stop worrying about this.

Comment: @Trevor what sort of info do you require about the transmitter?

Comment: Though, it may be more or less irrelevant, I think it's worth mentioning what frequency band the radio operates in.

Comment: @kjgregory it works between 30 Mhz to 90 Mhz.

Comment: Also for anyone interested,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66ZwuNoNgx4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IRCq0fbX48

Comment: depends, are you launching an emp attack?

Comment: Very long comment stream shows this is mostly opinion based answers at best. VTC.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the power of the transmitter and the wavelengths involved, the probability of the transmission interfering with the cell phones ability to communicate with the tower or wifi or whatever is fairly high though not damagingly, especially if the phone is really close to the antenna.

The probability of the transmission generating a damaging arc across some junction within the cell-phone is much much less, probably close to, but not zero. Distance also matters. A few inches or millimeters is much more likely to do damage than say six feet.

The risks are probably slight, but as such, why take the risk. When working in the vicinity of this stuff, unless you REALLY need to use your cell-phone in there, which you should not, leave it outside.

Comment: Trevor - just to clarify, you mentioned that I shouldnt use the cell phone as in make a call? 

In the scenario that I'm not making the phone call but the phone is switched on, are risks still the same? Because in essence the antenna of a phone is always working?

And does the 30Mhz-90Mhz change your answer in any way?

Comment: @TheBrokenBee  if the transmit from the antenna is going to kill the phone it wont matter if you are making a call or not. I meant, you should not need your phone in there anyway. If you don't when why take the risk.

Comment: Thanks! Would switching it off make any difference? I am just trying to understand how EM waves work - sorry!

Comment: @TheBrokenBee what can happen is enough voltage can be generated between two points to cause a spark to jump across or through something. That can happen with or without power on the device. When it does, recovery is less than guaranteed. You would have to have your phone really close to the antenna though and or the transmitter would need to be really strong.

Answer (score 0):

Cell phones have to survive ESD hits to the case, including right where the internal antenna is placed.

I'd not worry.